# Depreciation of value

Tags: exponential-function, percentages

I need help finding out at which percentage a car's value decreases by each year.

It changes by the same percentage each year, and by year $5$ it's value has decreased from $325000$ to $70000$. By what percentage does it decrease each year?

I have tried using the formula $70000$ = $325000x^\frac 15$

Dividing each side to isolate $x^\frac 15$, therefore getting:

$x^\frac 15 = 0.22$ and raising both sides to 5:

$x = 0.00052$ but I fail to extrapolate the percentage decrease from this.

Comment: We'll be glad to help you but you'll need to tell us what you have tried, how far have you progressed with this problem etc. Please take this [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) where you'll find out how to ask a question on this site.

Comment: I have tried 70000 = 325000x^1/5
Dividing both sides by 325000 to isolate x^1/5, therefore getting:
x^1/5 = 0.22
Raising both sides to 5:
x = 0.00052
Supplementing this into the formula checks out but I fail to extrapolate the percentage decrease from this.

Comment: please add that directly to your question body, also try to use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: Rethink the logic behind the formula you "tried".  If it decreases by a factor of $x$ each year then the five year equation is $70 = 325x^5$.

Comment: @EthanBolker I think I understand. Starting with $70 = 325x^5$, dividing, and taking the 5th root out of both sides instead I get $x = 0.74$. Supplementing this into the formula I get $\approx 70000$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, So a $26\%$ annual depreciation leads to the approximately $80\%$ in five years.